# How do I do monkeypatching in python?

Tags: python, monkeypatching

I've had to do some introspection in python and it wasn't pretty:

```
name = sys._getframe(1).f_code
name = "%s:%d %s()" %(os.path.split(name.co_filename)[1],name.co_firstlineno,name.co_name)
```

To get something like

```
foo.py:22 bar() blah blah
```

In our debugging output.

I'd ideally like to prepend anything to stderr with this sort of information -- 
Is it possible to change the behaviour of print globally within python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A print statement does its IO through "sys.stdout.write" so you can override sys.stdout if you want to manipulate the print stream.

Answer (score 1):

The python [inspect](http://www.python.org/doc/current/lib/module-inspect.html) module makes this a lot easier and cleaner.